a key that opens any door
a. You can find a key to open any door.
b. You can find a key that opens any door.
I think these sentences mean different things. I think (a) means there is a key for any door, and (b) means there is a key that can open all doors.
Is that correct?
Is (a) ambiguous? Could it mean the same as (b)?
Manu thanks

You are correct. The key in sentence b. would be a master key.

You are not correct. Both sentences can carry both meanings. Only context determines whether you're referring to the existence of master / skeleton keys, or to the fact that every door has a "lock-specific" key.

They're both ambiguous, but I agree with you about their dominant interpretations.
If one is more ambiguous than the other, though, I'd say it's the other way round: (b) is possible to interpret as (a), especially if you imagine it reworded like this:

Any door, you can find a key that opens it.

The question is of course how "a key" distributes over "any door". To my intuition, the relative clause naturally yields the interpretation that we are qualifying a single key, whereas the prepositional phrase seems to match a given key to a given door — perhaps under the influence of expressions like "a chicken in every pot" and "an outfit for any occasion".

One might argue that the master key interpretation demands the word "every", not "any". That would indeed remove the ambiguity in (b), but would actually not change the interpretation of (a).

A logician would never reword it that way! As every logician knows, "There exists A such that, for all B,..." is not at all the same as "For all B, there exists A such that...". So it's not surprising that your final example completely changes the interpretation.

@TonyK Ha, fair. To be more precise, both are logicians' wordings, and they capture different meanings. And the more I ponder it, the more I disagree with my own statement about how unambiguous it is (one really does need the universal and existential quantifiers to get around the ambiguity of English, even with more helpful syntax!). I'll remove it.

In non-technical language, another way to disambiguate the second case might be to say that “There is a key that opens all doors.”  The first case is harder; a more idiomatic way might be “Every door has a key that opens it.”

@gidds For the second meaning, I strongly suspect that the pronoun is helping us in both our examples. Somehow it feels like you couldn't have that reference without distributing a key to each door.

Both of your sentences are ambiguous, and each illustrates how the ambiguity of natural language can cause trouble in contexts where precision is required. A mathematician or logician would recognize this ambiguity as arising from the interaction between two forms of quantification. The existence quantifier (canonically expressed as there exists a … such that) and the universal quantifier (canonically for all).
The two possible interpretations of your example sentences can be expressed unambiguously by

There exists a key k such that for all locks L, k unlocks L

and

For all locks L there exists a key kL such that kL unlocks L.

This language, together with the use in the second sentence of the subscript L, makes it clear that the first of my pair of sentences asserts that some single key opens all locks while the second asserts that to each lock corresponds a key that will unlock it (but perhaps no other lock). An even less ambiguous variant of my second sentence would replace For all locks by For each lock.
An analogous pair of arithmetic examples is

For every counting number n there exists a counting number m such that n < m,

which implies that there are infinitely many counting numbers and is true, and

There exists a counting number m such that for every counting number n, n < m,

which implies that there is an infinite counting number and also that there exists a counting number less than itself, both of which are false.
Syntactically, each sentence in this last pair is constructed from the expression (mathematical clause) n < m, which is successively quantified by both quantifiers. The difference between the sentences’ meanings arises from the order in which the quantifiers are composed (which quantifier is applied to the result of having first applied the other).

@TonyK, I am guessing that it is you who downvoted my answer.  If that is correct, I’d love to know why so it can be improved.
